# Mongoose - How to search for a partial string match and then sort the results by score?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, search, mongoose

I'm creating a back-end for a web app using Node, Express, Mongoose, and Mongodb.  I'm trying to run a partial search on some user profiles with a name field and an array of tags so that "re" will return profiles with a tag array or name that contains "red" and "blueish" will return profiles with a tag array or name that contains "blue"

I found the syntax to add regex expressions.  Something along the lines of:

```
    Profile.find(.0
        { "tags": { "$regex": "re", "$options": "i" } },
        function(err,docs) { 
            str = JSON.stringify(docs, null, 4); 
            console.log(str)
        } 
    );
```

I'm also trying to score them and sort the results.  I found another stack overflow post that is along the lines of:

```
Profile.find({ "$text": { "$search": input } })
    .select({ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } })
    .sort({ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } })
    .exec(function(err,result) {
str = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4); 
console.log(str)
    }
);
```

But after reading the docs, I'm still a but fuzzy on how to combine the two concepts.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

{tag: /re/i} will return red, but blueish can't be done with regex because it's longer than blue.  Full text indexes will not search partial words.

We just implemented a full text search with nicknames which works very well for American names.  So someone types 'bob' and we bring back Rob, Robert, etc..  If that's what you are trying to do I can share the info.

Comment: That's great!  Thanks Rob!